# Why Oracle Rest Service returns 404 Not Found?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I have Apex 21 & ORDS installed. Apex works properly.

I have the following RESTful service module:

[image]

Whenever I access the module url, I'm getting the error **404 Not Found.**

ORDS is enabled for the schema.

[image]

Why is the module not working?

Answer (score 2):

> Whenever I access the module url

Nothing is configured in ORDS to provide a response at the module level, only the TEMPLATE level, and that only if you have a HANDLER defined for the method being used.

You can go to your API, or you can go to the description (OpenAPI Catalog) of the APIs in your module.

- Good: GET http://example.com/ords/myschema/test/1
- Bad: GET http://example.com/ords/myschema/test
- Good: GET http://example.com/ords/open-api-catalog/myschema/test/

[image]

Also for anyone else reading this, you can use APEX with ORDS, but you don't HAVE to use APEX with ORDS.

ORDS also has a native IDE for developing REST APIs, as shown in my screenshot. [You can read more about this here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2021/09/top-5-reasons-to-use-database-actions-rest-workshop-to-build-rest-apis-for-oracle-database/)

*Disclaimer: I'm the product manager at Oracle responsible for Oracle REST Data Services, aka ORDS.*